# No such file or directory mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am getting the following error while trying to connect to a database with mysql with php:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Users/minimoe/db.php on line 5
```

Here is the code that I ran:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','','','scheduler');
echo $db;
```

(I've also attempted to replace the second parameter with 'root' as well but this changes nothing)
**Edit:**
I've also tried: mysqli_connect('localhost','minimoe','','scheduler'); but this hasn't worked 
I've also tried: mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','scheduler'); but this hasn't worked
 **/ end of edit**

**So my question is: How can I connect to my database using mysql and php and fix this error?**

Some info:
1. I am using php built in web server by running php -S localhost:3306 
2. php version 5.6.30 
3. Server version: 5.7.18 Homebrew

Extra info: 
However I ran the following code using postgresql (I created a test db in psql) and it worked fine:

```
 $db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=scheduler user=minimoe password=''");
```

**Because I am fairly certain this question will be flagged as a duplicate, even though I haven't found an answer that will work for me, yet (although I have not googled the entirety of the vast web**  
 
I have tested several other similar questions answers in stack overflow to no avail, yet.

Some answers in other stack overflows that hasn't worked for me after trying them: 
1. replacing mysql_connect with mysqli_connect (because I'm already using this) 
2. replacing localhost with http://127.0.0.1/, this doesn't work for me either

3. replacing mysqli_connect with mysql() function

I hope I've provided enough info, comment if you need anything else to solve this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must have set a password while setting up mysql. If you did so, try:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','YOUR_PASSWORD','scheduler');
```

Comment: right, when I downloaded mysql I believe the password was auto created, as a random string of characters (something like 'eeWlXMPZw1&-') I have swapped the password with this but it does not work either. Also this may be relevant:  when I go into mysql from the command line I can do "mysql -u root" and it opens mysql without requesting a password

Answer (score 0):

In a previous comment you stated you used root as the username have you tried that?

`mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','scheduler');`

Comment: I have tried that as well and that hasn't fixed it. I have now edited my question to include the fact that I've used mysqli_connect('localhost','root',' ','scheduler'); as well